# Why are the matrices sizes are different?

Tags: matlab

I have a `0`/`1` values matrix `magnitude` and another matrix `edgels`. Both are 450x450 double. I want to keep only the cells in edgels which correspond with the `1` values in `magnitude` and zero the rest. I am trying the following operation:

```
edgels(magnitude==1)=edgels;
```

I am getting the error:

> In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

- Why are they not the same size?
- What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: What about the rest of the values that are not 1? What should these be set to?  You are also getting that error because `magnitude == 1` gives you a binary mask of 0 / 1 and by logical indexing, the total number of non-zero values in `magnitude == 1` must match the total number of elements you are assigning to `edgels`, which is not the case.

Comment: @rayryeng sorry. see edit.

Comment: `edgels(magnitude==1)` has `numel` of the entries equal to `1` while `edgels` is the full matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because `magnitude == 1` gives you a binary mask of 0 / 1 and by logical indexing, the total number of non-zero values in `magnitude == 1` must match the total number of elements you are assigning to `edgels`, which is not the case.

The easiest way to do what you ask would be to find all values in `edgels` where the magnitude is **not** 1, or 0, and set those values to 0.

```
edgels(magnitude == 0) = 0;
```

However, if you want to go with your logic, you would first create a zeros matrix, then modify the positions where `magnitude == 1` in the corresponding locations in the output:

```
out = zeros(size(edgels));
out(magnitude == 1) = edgels(magnitude == 1);
```

Take notice on the left and right hand side.  The total number of elements that need to be copied over are the same.

Another alternative I can provide is to simply multiply `magnitude` and `edgels` element-wise where the multiplication yields a result of 0 if some element in `magnitude` is equal to 0 and is untouched otherwise:

```
out = edgels .* double(magnitude);
```

Note that you need to cast `magnitude` to the same type as `edgels` in order for the multiplication to work or else MATLAB will give you an error about multiplying matrices of different types.